# Does the 'Internet of Things' fall under Computer Networking?

Tags: masters, computer-science, thesis

I'm currently a MSc Computer Networking student and I recently became acquainted with the internet of things. I've fallen completely in love with this new area and I would love to base my dissertation on this area.

The problem is, I'm unsure if "The internet of things" falls academically within the scope of computer networking at the MSc level. My school is currently "closed" for the summer break, so getting to a lecturer before September is rather difficult. I'll like to know if this is an "okay" topic for me to base my dissertation on for my course, so as to use my summer to do some deeper reading on the subject.

Comment: Whether something is an acceptable thesis topic is entirely up to your advisor/committee; we can't answer that question.  But if you're interested, why **not** do some deeper reading?

Answer (score 4):

I expect you'd have to argue that (some aspect of) current approaches to networking either won't scale to an Internet of Things (IoT), or else will need to be done differently because of device characteristics -- in other words, the networking aspects of IoT will have to be done differently somehow.  If you can do that, that could form the basis for a thesis.

Answer (score 3):

This question can be better answered in cs.stackexchange.com. I suggest that the moderators move it there if they dont find it suitable.

The Internet of Things is very huge for a Master or PhD thesis. It's like saying I want to solve the problem of the *Internet*. You should be more specific about what you want to solve. The problems of IoT are separated into *layers*. What will interest you the most is the *networking layer*. This layer is very similar to the OSI model of the Internet. There are tons of unsolved problems in this layer, and tons of others already solved (because they are old problems already found in the Internet).

Suggested problem domains: the services in the Internet of Things, naming resolution in IoT, objects integration in the IoT, objects networks in IoT, security and privacy in IoT, ...

or simply look for conferences about IoT, collect a set of similar papers, read them carefully and find an idea of a good thesis.

Comment: The first question of migration is always, "is it on-topic here?" In this case, I think the answer is "yes". I do agree that it may be *more* on-topic there, and you may want to talk to some of the CS folks in their [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science) to get some advice as well.

Comment: _services in the Internet of Things, naming resolution in IoT, objects integration in the IoT, objects networks in IoT, security and privacy in IoT, ..._ — All of those sound like lifetime research programs, not MS thesis topics.

Comment: @JeffE .. yup, you're right. this is why I said _problem domains_. They can all be considered under _networking_ though.